# Firebase Auth State is lost after updating app from Swift to Flutter

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have an App in, live in the AppStore developed in Swift where I use `Firebase Auth`. Everything is working fine. In the next update the app will be a Flutter App, but also using the same Firebase Backend, including Auth.

When I test the app, the `authState` is working fine. The user is still logged in after an app restart.

**HOWEVER** when I got the old app, update it via TestFlight to the new version, the user always gets logged out after an app restart. The only fix I found is deleting the app (new version) and installing  it again.

Is this a known issue? Is there something I can do? This is super frustrating for old users of my app, who update to the new version.

This is how I keep track of the `authState`:

```
  static bool isLoggedIn() {
    if (_isLoggedIn == null) {
      _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        _isLoggedIn = user?.uid != null;
      });
      _isLoggedIn = _firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid != null;
    }
    return _isLoggedIn ?? false;
  }
```

Also, I got this method inside my `main`, so a new user will be logged out the first time he opens the new app:

```
 static Future<void> signOutUserIfUserDeinstalledAndReinstalledApp() async {
    bool? isFirstStart = await LocalStorageService.getData(
      key: LocalStorageKeys.isFirstStart,
    );
    if (isFirstStart == null && !kIsWeb) {
      // await PushNotificationService.cancelAllNotifications();
      await LocalStorageService.clear();
      await signOut(deleteMessaingToken: false);
      await LocalStorageService.setBool(
        key: LocalStorageKeys.isFirstStart,
        value: false,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: They may be slight differences How a native app stores its tokens and how a flutter application. So in that case the flutter app might be unable to recognise the  ongoing session or tokens.

Comment: @udi sounds reasonable, but I couldn't find anything ons the Firebase docs about this..

Comment: How can you verify this: “ The only fix I found is deleting the app (new version) and installing it again.” ?

Comment: @Nerdy Bunz I tested it myself with TestFlight and also other users. Same result for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using the method channel. It's bit tricky but it's possible .

So we can create a method channel to check on the platform(on iOS) to check for the user details, auth status and session. I think you are pretty good with swift/objective c so it won't be an issue.

I am not good with swift, just creating a structure so you can get the idea. Following code is for battery but you can do the same for FirebaseAuth from swift side.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

enum ChannelName {
  static let user = "samples.flutter.io/user"
  static let authStatus = "samples.flutter.io/authStatus"
}

enum AuthState {
  static let signedIn = "signedIn"
  static let signedOut = "unauthentic"
}

enum MyFlutterErrorCode {
  static let unavailable = "UNAVAILABLE"
}

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, FlutterStreamHandler {
  private var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    guard let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController else {
      fatalError("rootViewController is not type FlutterViewController")
    }

<-----replace following code with returning user details----->
    let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: ChannelName.battery,
                                              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
      [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
      guard call.method == "getBatteryLevel" else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
      }
      self?.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)
    })
    <-----till here----->

<-----replace following code with auth status----->
    let chargingChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: ChannelName.charging,
                                              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    chargingChannel.setStreamHandler(self)
<-----till here----->
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

<----Replace with user auth---->
  private func receiveBatteryLevel(result: FlutterResult) {
    let device = UIDevice.current
    device.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    guard device.batteryState != .unknown  else {
      result(FlutterError(code: MyFlutterErrorCode.unavailable,
                          message: "Battery info unavailable",
                          details: nil))
      return
    }
    result(Int(device.batteryLevel * 100))
  }

  public func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?,
                       eventSink: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
    self.eventSink = eventSink
    UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    sendBatteryStateEvent()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(AppDelegate.onBatteryStateDidChange),
      name: UIDevice.batteryStateDidChangeNotification,
      object: nil)
    return nil
  }

  @objc private func onBatteryStateDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    sendBatteryStateEvent()
  }

  private func sendBatteryStateEvent() {
    guard let eventSink = eventSink else {
      return
    }

    switch UIDevice.current.batteryState {
    case .full:
      eventSink(BatteryState.charging)
    case .charging:
      eventSink(BatteryState.charging)
    case .unplugged:
      eventSink(BatteryState.discharging)
    default:
      eventSink(FlutterError(code: MyFlutterErrorCode.unavailable,
                             message: "Charging status unavailable",
                             details: nil))
    }
  }

  public func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    eventSink = nil
    return nil
  }

<-----till----->
}
```

On Flutter side

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PlatformChannel extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlatformChannel({super.key});

  @override
  State<PlatformChannel> createState() => _PlatformChannelState();
}

class _PlatformChannelState extends State<PlatformChannel> {
  static const MethodChannel methodChannel =
      MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/battery');
  static const EventChannel eventChannel =
      EventChannel('samples.flutter.io/charging');

  String _batteryLevel = 'Battery level: unknown.';
  String _chargingStatus = 'Battery status: unknown.';

  Future<void> _getBatteryLevel() async {
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      final int? result = await methodChannel.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
      batteryLevel = 'Battery level: $result%.';
    } on PlatformException {
      batteryLevel = 'Failed to get battery level.';
    }
    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_onEvent, onError: _onError);
  }

  void _onEvent(Object? event) {
    setState(() {
      _chargingStatus =
          "Battery status: ${event == 'charging' ? '' : 'dis'}charging.";
    });
  }

  void _onError(Object error) {
    setState(() {
      _chargingStatus = 'Battery status: unknown.';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(_batteryLevel, key: const Key('Battery level label')),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _getBatteryLevel,
                  child: const Text('Refresh'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text(_chargingStatus),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: PlatformChannel()));
}
```

this answer could be improved this is just a reference way. any help will be appreciated.

ref: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels

for continuous listen(stream): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel_swift

Comment: I would need a way to "transfer" authDetails from the old swift app to the flutter app. Your idea of using Platform Channels seems like a valid approach, but also quite complex and unfortunately I don't write Swift -Code anymore... But if nothing helps, I will give it a try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Sounds like bug/oversight by Firebase (Flutter implementation does not account for this edge case) or perhaps a unexpected behavior in your own code.

But since we know that it has something to do with some kind of conflicting remnant in the user’s local data and settings, and we know that it works properly as long as the user settings and data are cleared (since that’s the only difference between an update, and a reinstall), as long as there’s nothing critical in the users data and settings, a potential workaround would be to have your updated Flutter version to contain an initialization routine that clears the user data and settings first (as long as it’s the first time that the new version is being run).

Either that or its time to build a minimal complete example project and start analyzing how the Firebase auth implementation.

// ——————————————- original:

The fact of whether a user is authenticated or not (user == null or not) is only known to (determined by) the local device (not the backend) by means of a stored session token.

There must be a difference (between Flutter and ios Firebase auth implementation) in where and how this token is stored.

I dont see how this could be solved.

Also dont see why it should be a huge inconvenience —- I am unexpectedly logged out of apps all the time and I just shrug and log back in.  Its only going to happen once.

Comment: thats the thing. It always happens. The authState will always be lost after an app restart, until you completely reinstall the app. Otherwise youre right, it wouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: OK I understand it better now.

Comment: tried clearing everything. SharedPrefs, Cache, and SecureStorage. Nothing fixes the issue. Only a reinstall. :(